# How to add a timer to my spinner in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Am making a react-native app and I have a spinner which shows up when the user is signing up in the application. I want to add a timer to my spinner so if a user tries to register and it takes time to register maybe because of network the spinner should stop. Its just like a network kind of timeout.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what you have tried, before we can help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the spinner that you want a timer on, but your network request.  Create a component that has only one job, showing the spinner.  Pass to the component a property that lets it know if the spinner should be shown or not.  When your network request times out, change the property for the component to disable the spinner.

I think the real question is how to have a response timeout for your fetch.  There is a big discussion about it here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2556

If you truly just want the spinner to go away, then in the component that controls your spinner, just do a setTimeout that changes the state of the component to turn off the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable called `issuedRequest`, like

```
var issuedRequest = false;
```

When the request is issued, you can set

```
issuedRequest = true;
```

start the spinner and send the request. In the request callback you can set

```
issuedRequest = false;
```

After you have sent the request, you can do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (issuedRequest) {
        //Stop spinner
    }
}, 2000);
```

Alternatively, if you can set a timeout callback to your request, then you could do that.